# Automatically close Terminal after script execution

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

How do I automatically close the Terminal after script execution?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/sh-scripts/
./start.sh &
// ??? how to close Terminal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you call this script code you posted from within another shell. If you want the Terminal.app to be quit, you can use a simple [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) command:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
```

The same goes for iTerm2, or any other application. Just change its name in `"Terminal"`. Or, to quit the frontmost app, as @Lri mentions:

```
osascript -e 'quit app (path to frontmost application as text)'
```

If your script instead is run non-interactively, then it should suffice to `exit` it. The terminal window will not close though unless you change the terminal's settings:

[image]

Comment: You could also just quit the current app with `osascript -e 'quit app (path to frontmost application as text)'`.

Comment: And if you just need the current session’s tab / window to be closed, `exit` will do just fine.

Comment: @kopischke No, that'll just exit the script being run. The terminal tab / window containing the shell the script was invoked in will stay.

Comment: @slhck: ah, my bad – this needs to be set in the preferences for your session in Terminal.app. Default is, as you correctly stated, to not close the window – I changed that and forgot about it. So: **`exit` will also close the terminal window / tab if your “Shell → On exit” session preference in Terminal.app is set to “Close window” or “Close window if no error occurred”.**

Comment: The OP runs a script though. Try it: create a shell script, then add `exit` at the end, and run that script from a terminal window. The script exits but the window stays @kop

Comment: @slhck: I did, closes it on mine, but that is because I set it to do so. Also: synchronous commenting :) – see my revised comment.

Comment: No I meant something different. If you open a terminal window and call a shell script from Bash, and that script exits, Bash won't exit, and so won't the terminal @kop

Comment: @slhck: if you background the script, as OP does in his code, you are free to `exit` afterwards. Tested **exactly** that :).

Comment: But if you run that piece of code starting with the hashbang from another shell, you will exit that tiny script if you type exit. Not the shell that started it. I'm not talking about the script.sh & line here — this is irrelevant. Will add an example layer. @kop

Comment: @slhck: you are right – I’m assuming this is run interactively (yeah, I know the hashbang line does’t make any sense in that context – but neither does asking about closing Terminal when running a `.sh` script file directly, and why go to the trouble of having a shell script file that does nothing but launch another?). Anyway, never mind, your solution works fine and independently of session settings, so +1 as far as I’m concerned.

Comment: I have no idea about the context here so I guess you're right that a simple exit will do if the terminal is set up correctly :) @kop

Answer (score 1):

If you want your bash script (e.g. your executable **.sh** file) to **kill** the OS X Terminal application after the script execution is done, just add this line to the end of your script:

```
kill `ps -A | grep -w Terminal.app | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 1):

At Linux a script like this can be use to kill ONLY the opening terminal and not all of them:

````
#!/bin/bash -e

function kill_open_terminal {
  local child_pid=$1
  if [[ $child_pid == 1 ]]; then
    return 1
  fi
  local parent_pid=$(ps -p $child_pid -o ppid=)
  if [[ $child_pid == $parent_pid ]]; then
    return 1
  fi
  local parent_command=$(ps -p $parent_pid -o comm= | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
  if [[ -n $parent_command ]] && [[ $parent_command == *term* ]]; then
    kill $parent_pid
  else
    kill_open_terminal $parent_pid
  fi
}

kill_open_terminal $$ || {
  echo "Unable to find open terminal to close"
}```

Just change the tk_parent_command part to match the macOS terminal commands
````